What is the meaning of the exclamation point as the icon for Google Colab?
The symbol for Google Colab is an orange infinity sign.
However, and for the first time, upon starting a new document today, the icon had changed to an exclamation point:

What is the meaning of this change? Is there an issue with Colab at Google, or is it trying to say something about my own account?
